# How to generate the PDF for printing in Dot Matrix Printer using iTextSharp?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, printing, pdf-generation, itext

I have been using iTextSharp for generating the PDF documents to print pre-printed paper in A4 size. Our company has decided to use the Dot Matrix Printer for printing the documents. So I had to make modifications to code accordingly.

1. Fonts are not clear while printing from the PDF.
2. Alignments are not ok. I could not move the first line above the existing margin.

Please provide a good solution to handle this.

Comment: You should ask question instead of asking an all in one solution...

Comment: Furthermore you had better first determine how generally PDFs can be optimized for your new printing process; as a second step you can go ahead and ask how to implement these optimizations using a given PDF library. This is because there surely are experts for the first issue and experts for the second one, and the intersection of these sets of experts may be way smaller than the union.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For problem 1, changing the printer settings to higher CPI helped the print quality better.
For problem 2, got to keep testing with the X & Y axis variation in the program, until the alignment is ok.

Hope it helps someone.